# Personalize the first \addConstraint using optidef package

Tags: macros, packages, package-options, optidef

I have this MWE where I have used [`optidef`](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/optidef/optidef.pdf) package, a specific
library for *optimization problems*.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[short]{optidef}


\begin{document}
\begin{mini!}
{\scriptstyle x}{f(x+3)}{}{}
\addConstraint {a+b_k}{=0 ,}{k=0,\ldots, p -1}&<-----gives the word "s.t."
\addConstraint {c+d_k}{=5b ,\quad }{k=0, \ldots,p+3}
\end{mini!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> Is it possibile to changed the canonic `s.t.` (orange rectangle) with another word?

This is a screenshot of the documentation:

[image]

Comment: What would be the italian terms? Vincolato? Sotto vincoli?

Comment: @Bernard I don't know :-( It is there in the guide. Now I put a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is not designed for internationalisation, so I propose a solution with `xpatch` for the `\bodySubjectToDefinition` command, which is reponsible for the text printed in short and long form. I only touched upon the short form. Not knowing the exact italian translation, I opted for the abbreviation `s.v.` (for Sotto Vincoli – ‘under the constraints’):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[short]{optidef}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\bodySubjectToDefinition}{\kern 0.1em s.t.}{\kern 0.1em s.v.}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{mini!}
{\scriptstyle x}{f(x+3)}{}{}
\addConstraint {a+b_k}{=0 ,}{k=0,\ldots, p -1}
\addConstraint {c+d_k}{=5b ,\quad }{k=0, \ldots,p+3}
\end{mini!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful Bernard.+1 and accept it.

Comment: B.t.w., if you want to modify the long version as well, there is an `\ifthenelse` in the definition of the command, and it is on lines 139–150 of `optidef.sty`.

Comment: Thank a lot lot lot ...for your suggestion and for the answer.

Comment: A lot lol ? ;o)